# Loop sum excluding one column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                   (1,2,3,4,5,6),
                   (1,2,3,4,5,6)], columns=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])

Out:
    a b c d e f
0   1 2 3 4 5 6
1   1 2 3 4 5 6 
2   1 2 3 4 5 6
```

and I want to get the sum of all the elements of the dataframe, always excluding one column. In this example the desired outcome would be:

```
60 57 54 51 48 45
```

I have found a solution that seems to do the job, but I'm pretty sure there must be a more efficient way to do the same:

```
for x in df.columns:
    df.drop(columns = x).sum().sum()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rsub.html) for subtract from right side summed rows by `df.sum(axis=1)`, last add `sum` for sum per columns:

```
s = df.rsub(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).sum()
print (s)
a    60
b    57
c    54
d    51
e    48
f    45
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice, it's not common that rsub is useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simply subtract the total sum with the sum per column. This is efficiently done using an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
out = (s:=df.sum()).sum()-s
```

output:

```
a    60
b    57
c    54
d    51
e    48
f    45
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way: Subtract the column sums from the total sum of the DataFrame using broadcasting:

```
out = df.sum().sum() - df.sum()
```

Output:

```
a    60
b    57
c    54
d    51
e    48
f    45
dtype: int64
```